# Convert Data property value to Integer value

Tags: jena, ontology, literals

I have Data property value "Physics_Preferred_Category" which contains integer value 1,2 etc. 
    I want to get this value and perform calculations later on it. But it gives me exception/error.

```
 OntProperty phypref=model.getOntProperty(ns+ "Physics_Preferred_Category");
  RDFNode myValue =indiv.getPropertyValue(phypref);
Literal phliteral= model.createTypedLiteral(myValue);
 int phsum=phliteral.getInt(); //error highlight this line
 int calculate= phsum+1;
```

Comment: What sort of error? `Literal phliteral = myValue.asLiteral() ;` if myValue is the right kind of literal.

Comment: @Andy, myValue is the int value in the data type property.

Comment: And what error do you get? Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: The code spinnet is wrong. RDFNode can't be parameter of Model#createTypedLiteral. If there is really int-literal in the right side of property-assertion you should cast RDFNode to Literal and then get value: `indiv.getPropertyValue(phypref).asLiteral().getInt()`